# MVC 4 & Google Charts - How to pass data for Line Chart from Controller to View?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display information collected like this (Controller):

```
    public JsonResult GetDataAssets()
    {
        List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
        data.Add(new[] { "Day", "Kasse", "Bonds", "Stocks", "Futures", "Options" });
        data.Add(new[] { "01.03.", "200", "500", "100", "0", "10" });
        data.Add(new[] { "01.03.", "300", "450", "150", "50", "30" });
        data.Add(new[] { "01.03.", "350", "200", "180", "80", "40" });
        return Json(data);
    }
```

..in a Google Chart, like this (View):

```
function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($.post('GetDataAssets', {}).responseText);
    var options = {
        title: 'Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

This gives me a js exception stating data is not an array. It's probably not done with passing the data like i tried.. **How would i need to work the data returned by the ajax call to be in valid format?**

---

**Answer:**

This performed fetching & very flexible converting data as handed over already jsonyfied by the controller written above. Great Link: [this blog post](http://aspdotnetrazor.blogspot.de/2012/10/google-charts-in-mvc-4-c-razor.html)

```
               var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
               var rows = data.length;
               var cols = data[0].length;

               tdata.addColumn('string', data[0][0]);
               for (var i = 1; i < cols; i++) {
                   tdata.addColumn('number', data[0][i]);
               }

               tdata.addRows(data.length);
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                   tdata.setCell(i, 0, data[i][0]);
                   for (var j = 1; j < cols; j++) {
                       var value = parseInt(data[i][j]);
                       tdata.setCell(i, j, value);
                   }
               }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function drawChart() {

    $.post('GetDataAssets', {}, function(d){
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(d);
    var options = {
        title: 'Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    });
};
```

$.post() returns an XMLHttpRequest. Its initial responseText will be empty until request completes with status 4. What you are doing wrong is, you are passing XMLHttpRequest immediately.

**UPDATE**

Try this on your controller

```
public JsonResult GetDataAssets() {
        List<object> data = new List<object>();
        data.Add(new[] { "Day", "Kasse", "Bonds", "Stocks", "Futures", "Options" });
        data.Add(new[] { 01.03, 200, 500, 100, 0, 10 });
        data.Add(new[] { 01.03, 300, 450, 150, 50, 30 });
        data.Add(new[] { 12.15, 350, 200, 180, 80, 40 });
        return Json(data);
    }
```

Comment: Meanwhile, I've got it like you wrote, thanks to haim770's tip. Now the problem is that in my Controller, I create all data as string and Google chart does not like ints defined as string .. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @peter , at least one axis (vAxis or hAxis) should be an integer. Try returning List<object>. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Google Charts, but i do know that this line:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($.post('GetDataAssets', {}).responseText);
```

will not fill `data` with the `json` response from the server, since (unless otherwise specified) `ajax` requests are done in an asynchronous way.

This is the way to go about it:

```
var jsonData = null;

$.post('GetDataAssets',
       {},
       function(data) { jsonData = data; },
       'json');

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   function drawChart() {
          $.get('/Home/GetData', {},

   function (data) {
      var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

      tdata.addColumn('string', 'day');
      tdata.addColumn('number', 'kasse');
      tdata.addColumn('number', 'Bonds');
      tdata.addColumn('number', 'Stocks');
      tdata.addColumn('number', 'Futures');


      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          tdata.addRow([data[i].day, data[i].Kasse, data[i].Bonds, data[i].Stocks, data[i].Futures]);
      }

      var options = {
          title: "Year Wheel"
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(tdata, options);
  });
      }
```

Comment: Very nice. I really want this. Thanx a lot.